# Executing java mail program from unix box machine in which java is installed

Tags: java, jar, jakarta-mail

I have the below java program which I am executing from eclipse under windows  and it is working perfectly. Now I want to create a jar of it which I can make it from eclipse it self by creating a jar option now p, as I want to execute the same program from unix box machine in which java is installed please advise how I will test this same program from unix box machine in which java is installed and jdk is set, shall I go for jar creation process.

```
public class SSendEmail {

    MimeMessage mimeMessage = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException, Exception {
        String smtpHost = "11.1620.90.520";
        String mailSmtpPort = "192381";
        String mailTo[] = {"ena@rdbs.com"};
        String mailCc[] = {"sena@rdbs.com"};

        postEmailForBrokerageNotification(mailTo, mailCc, "k",
                "testSubject", "Body123", smtpHost, mailSmtpPort);
    }

    //Send email for broker post pay email notification 
    public static void postEmailForBrokerageNotification(String mailTo[], String mailCc[], String from, String subject, String text, String smtpHost, String mailSmtpPort) throws Exception, DocumentException, IOException {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
            properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", mailSmtpPort);
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

            //obtaining the session
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

            //Enable for debuging 
            emailSession.setDebug(true);

            Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(emailSession);

            if (mailTo != null) {
                InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[mailTo.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < mailTo.length; i++) {
                    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(mailTo[i]);
                }
                emailMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
            }

            InternetAddress[] addresscc = new InternetAddress[mailCc.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < mailCc.length; i++) {
                addresscc[i] = new InternetAddress(mailCc[i]);
            }
            emailMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.CC, addresscc);

            emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            emailMessage.setSubject(subject);

            emailMessage.setContent(text, "text/html");

            //Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html");

            messageBodyPart.setText(text);

            // Create a multipart message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            //  attachment part
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String filename = "c:\\sd-Spec_for_Data-Mapping_P3--SARALE_RETURNswap.xls";

            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            attachPart.setFileName(filename);

            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            // Send the complete message parts
            emailMessage.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(emailMessage);
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException messagingException) {
            messagingException.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(messagingException.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what issue are you facing when deployed in UNIX box?

Comment: There is no difference in jar creation/launching on virtual or real machine. Or you want to create the virtual machine and launch jar in it in one step?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking but it seems like a very basic question of "how do I run a Java program from the command line?"  There's lots of beginning Java tutorials that will help you with that.  You'll find some JavaMail-specific instructions in the [JavaMail README.txt file](https://javamail.java.net/docs/README.txt).